# Jenkins failed to connect to TFS

Tags: tfs, jenkins

I have been working on configuring Jenkins to connect to TFS server and all was working fine until we migrate some of our projects to TFS 2012.

Our Jenkins is running on a CI server as a service under local system account and the users will log into the Jenkins console using windows id as it is configured with Active directory

The job just connect to TFS server through command line utility which we started getting HTTP 404 error for TFS 2010 projects after we ran the build for one the TFS 2012 projects.

Here is the job log when it connects to TFS 2010 server

```
[Test] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson666032816381947801.bat

C:\Softwares\Jenkins-1.569\workspace\Test>"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio     11.0/Common7/IDE/tf.exe" workspaces /owner:domain\username /login:domain\username,password -   server:http://tfs2010Server:8080/tfs 

HTTP code 404: Not Found

C:\Softwares\Jenkins-1.569\workspace\Test>exit 100 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I copy the same command and run it in the command prompt on CI server it runs fine but running it through Jenkins fails for 2010.Also the job runs fine for TFS 2012 server

I am not sure if it is relevant, I also deleted the files under the cache folder inside my home and also the AppData/Mircosoft/Team Foundation inside Windows/System32/config folder as stated by many and yields no result.

At this point I have already spent 2 days but in vain.Not sure what is the difference in running the command through Jenkins than directly through the command line.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with 2010 and 2012? Do you have two separate instance of TFS, or you upgraded? Which version of Team Explorer is installed on Jenkins?

Comment: We have two instances of TFS one is 2010 and another is 2012 version.On the the Jenkins machine we installed 2012 Team exploer.

Comment: If it were a 401, I have some ideas, for a 404 we need more data. Fiddler may shed some light in this case.

Comment: The tf workspaces command requires a project collection URL. Can you check your script? You look like you're pointing to the TFS server, not a collection.

Comment: We tried that too and it yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance of TFS may be running on HTTPS not on HTTP as your -server parameter indicates.  If you have not already solved this issue, I'd check that you have the right URL.